# Wix project error in TFS build

Tags: tfs, wix

I am building a solution that contains a Wix v3.6 project on Team Foundation Server (TFS 2010). The solution also contains some other class library projects. The TFS build is unsuccessful with the following error:

light.exe : error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'Path\assembly.dll' with type ''.

I have checked that the file (assembly.dll) in question and it does exists at the given path. The file in question is actually the output of another project in the solution. Apart from this file there are other files that are successfully found by wix project in the same path location.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Does your WiX project have a project dependency set for the project that builds the missing dll? If not, it's probably an issue with the order of the build process.

Comment: Here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6734558/812540 This is how I fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be due to file path 'Path\assembly.dll' will be larger in characters as light.exe support max 255 (or 155 char not sure) characters only.

You can change compressed to no as compressed=no in . This will create some folders with dependent file along with installer in output path.

If possible try to give shorter name to buildoutput and dropfolders that you are using at build server with compressed="yes"